# Power Supply with Variable Output Level

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics

First of all, I'm sorry if this question turns out as a duplicate (since I absolutely have no idea about the keyword I should used).

I am trying to recreate a power supply (DC) which can have multiple output level. My model is Lex Solar Power Module (sadly its broken now, thus why I am trying to create my own)

[image]

Description about the module :
It supplied with 12V 2A adaptor, and able to deliver single 1-12V output with 0.5V increment/decrement based on the input ('+' or '-').
At first, I though it was only analog, but turns out its using STM32 as main controller.

So, my question is, what should I look for? What is the technical terms of this type of power supply, and perhaps along with an example of IC used.

**EDIT------------**
I forgot to mention one thing about the module characteristics, when constant load is used (i.e. 1K resistor), when the output is 1V, the current is 1mA, so does when the output is 5,6,7,8 V, the current is 5mA, 6mA, 7mA and 8mA. In short, current raise as the voltage raise.

If there any disambiguation about my question please ask, I will try to fix it. Thanks

Comment: By 'multiple output level' do you mean 'single adjustable output'?

Comment: Yes. It only has one output, but the voltage can be changed using touch capacitive sensors as shown on screen ('+' and '-') which change the output by + or - 0.5V

Comment: Note that there are ready-build modules available which do a similar job, for example: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/5A-Digital-Control-Power-Supply-DC-DC-Step-Down-Charge-Buck-Module-Voltmeter-/142045366249?hash=item21129047e9:g:ZFwAAOSwgZ1XqvRb  Although it is possible to make an exact functional duplicate of the device you have it will require a lot of work and knowledge.

Comment: @FakeMoustache thanks for the reference, it's kind of open up my mind. Actually I want to learn further about electronics by trying to make this.

Comment: *want to learn further about electronics* **Excellent !!** But if you have little experience then digital control and a switched converter might be a bit of a challenge. There are many small things you need to know, which are often learned by experience from a much simpler project. What you could do is find a power supply / lab supply project on the internet. There are many and at various levels. Pick one you think would be doable for you. Trying to make an all-singing-dancing supply as a first project might end in tears :-( better avoid that. My lab supply is also a the 3rd I build ;-).

Comment: @FakeMoustache I have like four iterations of constant current step-up converters for a simple 1A LED (LED array module, to be exact) that nominally works at 38V

Comment: My first "supply" was a model-train transformer with 2 fat smoothing capacitors and a LED ;-) (not really a proper power supply I know but did the job). The second is an LM200 based lineair supply with current limiter. The third is a dual L296 buck converter with switching pre-regulation and lineair secondary regulation. Also adjustable current limiting. 100% my own design. Still working after 25 years ! Notice how the complexity increases with projects.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Exactly. First iteration: Step-up to fixed 40V with series resistor that got too hot for its own good. Second iteration step-up with modifying the feedback voltage source to be proportional to current. Design awkwardness and releasing the magic smoke from the ONsemi step-up controller by using the wrong polarity to PWM the LED led to redesigns. Next iteration: screw readily-made controllers, I'm doing this with my own code and analog circuitry,most of the 12V->something step up converters either need a feedback voltage that I'd have to awkwardly multiply out of a low-side shunt…

Comment: … so adding an opamp to the complexity doesn't really help with estimating phase reserve of the controller. Therefore, it'll probably be a really small FPGA (lattice ICE40, for the existence of Yosys/ArachnePNR alone – I'm a Xilinx ISE/Vivado user and I hate that), the latter doing all the timing critical interfacing with analog comparators and MOSFET drivers (probably will use the 500mA "IR LED Pin" to drive the gate directly). Maybe I'll throw in a simple ADC based voltage slope estimator later on and see whether I can "smooth" out my switching.

Comment: Hello, gentlemen, good day! I'm grinning right now seeing the comment has become longer than my question XD. @FakeMoustache I do have an experience in digital control, simply put, I am into programming rather than electronics. But, why not both, right? Based on the comments of two of you,it seems that your experience is at different league than mine, can you point me to any reading materials that have the same concept with my description above?

Comment: I've notice that I am missing one description. Question edited.

Comment: Regarding your edit. Do you have a 1 kohm resistor as the load? I very much doubt "current raise as the voltage raise" being a function of this device.

Comment: @winny Yes, I am using 1K ohm load. Well, because after some readings about buck regulator, isn't a buck regulator draws greater current at lower voltage?

Comment: As I suspected. Please think of a buck converter as a way to lower the voltage and the output current will only depend on the load you connect. The converter does not "make" current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [buck regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter). The MCU is most likely used for handling the interface and supplying a reference voltage to the analog section of the device.

There are literally hundreds if not thousands of buck regulator devices; pick a vendor and look at their lineup. It is also not terribly difficult to build one from scratch using only discretes and MSI chips.

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio, I've read the link you gave, so far, here is my analysis about the concept of the original module (please correct me if I'm wrong): Input will change pwm level generates by MCU (whether its '+' or '-') at constant value so that the result from buck regulator is up or down by 0.5V?

Comment: @dpw that's reading a bit much into it. Ignacio just said that the MCU is probably used to generate a reference – and I'd agree with that assumption. So maybe the MCU is used to generate something between 0-3V as reference, depending on what buttons you've pressed, and then there's circuitry that compares the output of the buck regulator to multiple of that, and adjusts the buck regulator's operation accordingly. Whether anything of that happens with a PWM is details

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams after re-read your explanation about MCU, I think that my initial guess was wrong. Can you explain more about "the MCU is most likely used to ... and supplying a reference voltage to the analog section of the device". What "device" is it exactly? is it some kind of feedback using DAC?

Comment: @dpw: No, it's probably just a regulator that uses an op amp or two to determine the error between the reference and the output.